# selectively clear MySQL query cache (only clear one specific query)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-cache

I need to try & clear only a single query (actually a stored proc) from the cache in order to debug it & objectively determine if our optimizations are effective. It's on a client's production system that we have no backup for, and doing a db-wide query cache reset would be catastrophic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things on query cache:

- Individual queries are being cached and not stored procedures.
- Cache entries are invalidated once one of the tables that participates in the SQL is modified.

You can add the  SQL_NO_CACHE keyword in your queries in order to avoid caching.

Comment: AHA! Forgot all about no_cache directive. Thank you!